# How do remove pppoeconf from boot process

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet, network-manager

I recently upgraded from a BSNL ZTE ADSL modem to a Digisol wireless router+modem. When I had my previous modem, I used pppoeconf to set up my connection.

Now my modem connects itself, and I no more need pppoeconf. As pppoeconf disabled Network Manager, I couldn't use it. Then I tried starting the service, `sudo service network-manager start` and it works perfectly. The only problem is now I have to do this every time I boot, and while booting, the `Waiting for network configuration` message makes me wait three minutes or so. It's annoying. I want my three minutes back, along with network manager.

Please help me remove pppoeconf and revert to network manager.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

`sudo deborphan | sudo xargs apt-get -y remove pppoeconf --purge`

**If** you have **added** pppoeconf **to startup** uncheck or **remove** it.